# Dynamic output updation on a command line interface

Tags: c, command-line

I am eager to know how to print the output on a terminal screen similar to the one that of the 'top' command.

What I mean to say is .. dynamic updation of the existing output on terminal window.

A small c program or reference to appropriate resources is expected ....

Comment: You mentioned 'top' , can you give a hint as to your platform?

Comment: I did not get you .. I am using Linux machine .. and I am talking top command which displays the cpu and mem utilizations of various processes running in a linux macihne.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to check out [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) (or *curses, or whatever is appropriate for termio on your platform). [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) is also of interest :)

Comment: Seems ANSI escape sequences are really tough to program with .. might be the crude way of doing things ??

Comment: @codingfreak, I agree with tinkertim; ncurses is the way to go. It's also a pretty fun API to work with.

Comment: @codingfreak: I linked to escape sequences so you could see just how much pain ncurses (and others) save you.

Answer (score 1):

[Ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) (Unix-only I think) or [PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/) (portable) is the way to go.